# Applying restrictive clause to compound nouns

Tags: restrictive-clauses

> A renown foreign bakery and a locally owned bakery, which HAS won awards for its croissants, HAVE seen a significant decrease in the revenue since the biggest employer in the area shut down.

How do I rewrite the sentence so that the phrase "which has won awards...." applies to both the foreign and local bakery?

Comment: Bracketed with commas that's a non-restrictive clause.

Comment: You mean 'renown**ed** foreign bakery'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short way would be:

> ... which **have** won awards ...

However, to make fully clear, you should add:

> ... **both of** which **have** won awards ...

In this way you make it clear that you refer to both businesses, not only to one.